# прикладная математика для машинного обучения

Tags: математика, машинное-обучение

Сейчас занимаюсь бекенд-разработкой (на С++, немного Python). В целом нравится. Сейчас Появилась возможность заняться машинным обучением, в том числе пойти на второе высшее - прикладную математику. Как считаете нужно ли настолько глубоко погружаться в математику, чтобы быть хорошим специалистом в ML ?  Или достаточно базовых знаний математического анализа и линейной алгебры?

Comment: Теория вероятности ещё крайне нужна. Плюс статистика. Проблема в том, что дата сайентисты - это не программисты вообще. Я вот бэкэндщик на C# и Python и я уже несколько лет толком не могу устроиться куда-то поближе к машинному обучению. Проблема в том, что в компаниях нужны обычно чистые дата-сайентисты, которые хорошо рубят в статистику, тервер и прочие такие специфические штуки. А программисты там нужны только чтобы готовить данные для моделей и поддерживать модели в продакшене. Два разных мира вообще. Люди, которые просто умеют запустить XGBoost, не понимая, что там и как внутри - не нужны.

Comment: Вы бы указали первое свое высшее. Если оно "юриспруденция", а бекенд после кортких курсов, например, то да - идите на "прикладную математику", должно быть очень полезно. Если "вычислительные машины, комплексы системы и сети" - вряд ли стоит.

Answer (score 2):

Вот что на ваш "совершенно уникальный" вопрос отвечают люди, которые понимают что к чему.

https://towardsdatascience.com/the-roadmap-of-mathematics-for-deep-learning-357b3db8569b

https://mml-book.github.io/

https://habr.com/ru/company/skillbox/blog/663508/

http://ai-news.ru/2018/12/vazhnye_aspekty_matematiki_v_nauke_o_dannyh_chto_i_pochemu.html

https://www.datasciencecentral.com/tutorial-the-math-of-machine-learning-berkeley-university/

А вообще, если вы начинаете торговаться "а что стоит учить, а что нет, а может моих базовых знаний хватит что-бы не напрягаться" -  то думаю, вам не стоит соваться в ML, ибо там учить новое придется еще чаще чем в программировании.

Ну и неумение самостоятельно найти ответ на этот 100000 раз уже повторенный вопрос -  тоже весьма показателен для кандидата в специалисты по ML.

Comment: Да уж, особенно если до нейросетей дело дойдёт, то там каждый год какие-то новые SOTA варианты выкатывают, запаришься быть в курсе дел. Этим жить надо и постоянно учиться :)

Comment: Это надо любить, а не торговаться на тему "тут учим, а там - слишком глубоко" :-)

Comment: Не совсем согласен с "начинаете торговаться "а что стоит учить, а что нет" - всегда надо определяться с тем, что надо учить, а что - нет. Это не торговля, а разумное определение эффективного распределения усилий. Учиться я люблю и учусь постоянно, но до сих пор досадно, что в школе массу сремени потратил на ненужные предметы (экономическая география, биология и т.д.) по требованию родителей вместо фокуса на том, что было мне более нужно.

Comment: Ну мы же сейчас не про биологию, а про математику для того, кто стремиться стать специалистом по Машинному обучению.

Comment: @passant, принцип тот же. Глубоко ли надо знать сложную линейную алгебру? (нет - базовых знаний достаточно для подавляющего большинства). Уметь выводить и доказывать сложные леммы и теоремы для алгортмов? (не особо, практика важнее). Получать полностью второе высшее по прикладной математике, если первое "вычислительные машины и т.д."   - нет смысла, курсами лучше добирать. Я тоже хочу заниматься ML и как раз выбираю тщательно, на что тратить время. Я лучше три курса мат.статистики пройду углублённых, чем один мат.статистики + один лин.алгебры + один с доказательствами теорем для алгоритмов:-)